# How do I resize the text axis box of a graph in Excel 2016?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

The following image shows my current graph. The area in red is what I want to resize the text label box to in order to prevent the text from being cut off. However, I've searched everywhere for a way to resize the text label box but didn't succeed. I can resize the entire graph in Excel to show the full text of the text labels, but this becomes too broad to be displayed nicely in Word 2016 on A4 format. Ideally, I want the text label to cover about 80% of the width of the entire graph, and have the frequency bars cover the rest.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do this in Excel 2016. There is no way using built-in features to make this work. I have not tried or used any third party extensions yet, but I wasn't interested in that either.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found this setting in Excel 2013:

[image]

But I'm not sure how to *right align* the labels yet.  Will update if I find something.

Comment: I have that too, but it doesn't change the fact that the text is cut off, it literally just sets the distance, keeping the cutoff :-(

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answerFor those of you who just want to this one!resize vertical Axis: (works in O365 for sure).

DO NOT click on the Vertical Axis Text Box. DO CLICK on the top of the chart area (this is called the "Plot Area") (without clicking the data graph itself known as the "Series" data) Then select the ellipses in the upper left. Resize the Plot Area, and Resize, the Vertical Axis will adjust in proportion.

Select "Plot Area" and resize to change Width of Vertical Axis.

While this doesn't likely fix the problem of the original post, it matches the subject "resize text axis box". I've added this update since on O365 this is not intuitive at all.

[image: Expand graph area to change size of Vertical Axis text box.]

Answer (score 0):

The only way this is possible is to increase the width of the graph as you suggested. Then click on the chart area and decrease the width. This will result in a graph with wide margins but it is the only way to increase the width of horizontal labels.

Answer (score -1):

I have trying to solve the horizontal axis descriptions cut off by box for an hour.  Google search no help.  Here is a work around I figured out.  Click in chart.  Click on Design in Chart Tools. Click on Quick Layout. There is a picture of a layout with boxes directly below a bar chart.  Select that and your X axis descriptions fit in the boxes.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case Zimano had precised his needs